# Access variable from other function LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, controller

I'm trying to use the returned result from a function into another function. Here is my first function:

```
public function availableRooms(){
    if(isset($_POST['selectedDate'])){
        $checkInDateReceived = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['selectedDate']);
        $checkInDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($checkInDateReceived));
        $availableRooms = DB::table('rooms')
            ->leftJoin('reservations', function ($secondJoin) use($checkInDate) {
                $secondJoin->where('reservations.checkout_date', '<', $checkInDate);
            })
            ->leftJoin('reservation_room_rel', function ($firstJoin) {
                $firstJoin
                    ->on('reservation_room_rel.room_id', '=', 'rooms.id')
                    ->on('reservation_room_rel.reservation_id', '=', 'reservations.id');
            })
            ->where([
                ['rooms.status', '=', 1]
            ])
            ->whereNull('reservation_room_rel.room_id')
            ->get();
        return $availableRooms;
    }
}
```

And here is my second function:

```
public function returnAddReservation(){
    $availableRoomsRet = $this->availableRooms();
    $mealSupplement = new Meal;
    $accommodationSupplement = new AccommodationSupplement;

    $accommodationSupplements = $accommodationSupplement::where('status', 1)
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
    $mealSupplements = $mealSupplement::where('status', 1)
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
    return view('addReservation', [
        'availableRooms' => $availableRoomsRet,
        'accommodationSupplements' => $accommodationSupplements,
        'mealSupplements' => $mealSupplements
    ]);
}
```

First function returns correct result if it runs independently, but, when I `dd($availableRoomsRet)`it returns null. 
Any idea how to access properly `$availableRooms` from `public function availableRooms()` into `public function returnAddReservation()` ? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is the `var_dump` result of `$this->availableRooms()`  ? is it NULL ?

Comment: yes, it is null

Comment: then probably your query failed, please make sure that you got a query with results.